pythonのリスト内表記が良くわかりません。
七並べもどきの五並べを作っている途中なんですが、settingのself.turningの文が思い通りに行っていないようで具体的には削除しようとしている要素が削除されません。
どうすればよいのでしょうか？コード↓
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import random

SCREEN = Rect(0,0,400,415)

class Trump:
    def __init__(self):
        self.update = self.start
        self.C_x = []
        self.C_y = []
        self.turning = []
        self.memo = []
        self.flag = 1`

    def draw(self,GameBoard,screen,C_name):
        color = [(255,255,255),(255,224,32)]
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 36)
    
        
        for y in range(0,2):
            for x in range(0,6):
                if GameBoard[y][x] == 0:
                     pygame.draw.rect(screen, color[0], (70+60*(x-1), 100+110*y, 50, 90))
                
                if GameBoard[y][x] == 1:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color[0], (70+60*(x-1), 100+110*y, 50, 90))
                    text = font.render(C_name[10*y+(x-1)],True,(255,0,0))
                    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(70+60*(x-1)+25, 100+110*y+45))
                    screen.blit(text,text_rect)
                
                if GameBoard[y][x] == 2:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color[1], (70+60*(x-1), 100+110*y, 50, 90))

       
        for i in range(0,len(self.turning[0])):
            text = font.render(C_name[10*self.turning[0][i][0]+ self.turning[0][i][1]],True,(255,255,255))
            text_rect = text.get_rect(center = (100+40*i,400))
            screen.blit(text,text_rect)
                
        
    def start(self,GameBoard,click_x,click_y):
        C_all = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]
        random.shuffle(C_all) 
        self.C_x = C_all[:5]
        self.C_y = C_all[-5:]
        blocks_to_remove_x = []
        blocks_to_remove_y = []

        for block in self.C_x:
            if block[1] == 2:
                GameBoard[block[0]][block[1]+1] = 1
                blocks_to_remove_x.append(block)
        for block in self.C_y:         
            if block[1] == 2:
                GameBoard[block[0]][block[1]+1] = 1
                blocks_to_remove_y.append(block)
        
        for block in blocks_to_remove_x:
            self.C_x.remove(block)
        for block in blocks_to_remove_y:
            self.C_y.remove(block)
 
        self.update = self.search

    def search(self,GameBoard,click_x,click_y):
        
        for i in range(0,len(self.turning[0])):
            if GameBoard[self.turning[0][i][0]][self.turning[0][i][1]] ==1 or GameBoard[self.turning[0][i][0]][self.turning[0][i][1]+2] ==1:
                GameBoard[self.turning[0][i][0]][self.turning[0][i][1]+1] = 2
                self.memo.append(i)
        self.update = self.setting

    def setting(self,GameBoard,click_x,click_y):
        
        for i in self.memo:
            if click_y > 100 +110*self.turning[0][i][0] and click_y <100 +110*self.turning[0][i][0]+90 and click_x > 70+60*self.turning[0][i][1] and click_x <70+60*self.turning[0][i][1] +50:
                GameBoard[self.turning[0][i][0]][self.turning[0][i][1]+1] = 1
                self.turning[0] = [self.turning[0][i] for i in range(len(self.turning[0])) if i not in self.memo]
                self.flag = self.flag*(-1)
                GameBoard = [[6,0,0,0,0,0,6],[6,0,0,0,0,0,6]]
                break
            else:
                None
        self.update = self.search
        print(self.C_x)

    def run(self):
            if self.flag == 1:
                self.turning = [self.C_x, self.C_y]
            if self.flag == -1:
                self.turning = [self.C_y,self.C_x]

            
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN.size)

    C_name = {0:"A1", 1:"A2", 2:"A3", 3:"A4", 4:"A5", 10:"B1", 11:"B2", 12:"B3", 13:"B4",14:"B5"}
    C_all = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]
    GameBoard = [[6,0,0,0,0,0,6],[6,0,0,0,0,0,6]]
                #[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]
    Turning = []

    trump = Trump()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    click_x, click_y = 0,0

    while (1):
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()
        trump.run()
        trump.update(GameBoard,click_x,click_y)
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        trump.draw(GameBoard,screen,C_name)
        for event in pygame.event.get():        
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                click_x, click_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


「思い通りに行っていない」ことの詳細な説明を追記した方が良いでしょう。「具体的には削除しようとしている要素が削除されません。」だとあまり具体的とは言えないと思われます。元の状態がどのようなもので、残すか削除するかの対象はどのような条件(とそれがあらわす意味は何か)で判定するか、正常な結果はどのような状態になって欲しいか、そして問題が発生している状況ではどのような結果になっているか、といった事を説明できるように記述してみてください。あるいはそうした説明を考える過程で自分自身で回答を見つけられるかもしれません。その場合は自己回答でもしてください。

リスト内包表記をループ文に書き換えた場合は上手く行きますか？内包表記の書き方の問題なのかそもそものロジックが悪いの確かめてはどうでしょうか？
